# Div positioning with display:flex, justify-content: space-between leaves unwanted space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a row with label on the left and two columns with inputs on the right.

as you can see **position** y = 40 input is leaving space on the right, and that's what I want to avoid.

[image: what I have now]

```html
<div class="row-wrap">
    <p>Position</p>
    <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
            <input id="cx" name="cx" value="60">
            <label for="cx"> x </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
            <input id="cy" name="cy" value="40">
            <label for="cy"> y </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
  .column-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

 .column-controls{
    width: 60%;
  }

  .column-controls input {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .row-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

Because this `.column-wrap` isn't holding input tight, neither of two outer `.row-wrap`s can't place it more to the right (as **Background** input lower) justify-content works but this extra space on `.column-wrap` prevent it from looking great. How can I make this `.column-controls` group to be on the right?

lower I added a snippet for your convenience

```css
.settings form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.settings p {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.column-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-controls {
  width: 60%;
}

.column-controls input {
  width: 69%;
  text-align: center;
}

.row-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.heading {
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <form>
    <p class="heading">Properties (ellipse)</p>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Position</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cx" name="cx" value="60">
          <label for="cx"> x </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cy" name="cy" value="40">
          <label for="cy"> y </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Size</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="rx" name="rx" value="50">
          <label for="rx"> rx </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="ry" name="ry" value="50">
          <label for="ry"> ry </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <p> Background </p>
        <input id="fill" type="color" name="fill" value="#BDBBB8">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <p>Border</p>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke"> Color </label>
        <input id="stroke" type="color" name="stroke" value="#0000ff">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-width"> Width </label>
        <input id="stroke-width" name="stroke-width" value="2">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-dasharray"> Style </label>
        <select name="stroke-dasharray">
                    <option value="8, 10" selected="">
                        dashed
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="1, 4">
                        dotted
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="0">
                        solid
                    </option>
                
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `align-self: right` to `.column-controls input`

Comment: @JyotiPathania There is no such value as `right` for `align-self`

Comment: @LGSon Its works in firefox.. though the right value is `flex-end`

Comment: @JyotiPathania Then Firefox is terrible wrong....

Comment: @LGSon haha report that to firefox.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your space is being caused because your inputs are 69% width and aligned to the center of the cell, change the width to 100% and it will solve your problem:

```
.column-controls input {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

If you want a space between your column-wraps, add a max-width to them - in the below, I gave them a max width of 45%

```css
.settings form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.settings p {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.column-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  max-width:45%;              /* add this for the gap between column-wraps */
}

.column-controls {
  width: 60%;
}

.column-controls input {
  width: 100%;               /* change this so input reaches edge of cell */
  text-align: center;
}

.row-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.heading {
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <form>
    <p class="heading">Properties (ellipse)</p>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Position</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cx" name="cx" value="60">
          <label for="cx"> x </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cy" name="cy" value="40">
          <label for="cy"> y </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Size</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="rx" name="rx" value="50">
          <label for="rx"> rx </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="ry" name="ry" value="50">
          <label for="ry"> ry </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <p> Background </p>
        <input id="fill" type="color" name="fill" value="#BDBBB8">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <p>Border</p>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke"> Color </label>
        <input id="stroke" type="color" name="stroke" value="#0000ff">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-width"> Width </label>
        <input id="stroke-width" name="stroke-width" value="2">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-dasharray"> Style </label>
        <select name="stroke-dasharray">
                    <option value="8, 10" selected="">
                        dashed
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="1, 4">
                        dotted
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="0">
                        solid
                    </option>
                
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>
```

As per your comment, if you want to go the padding for the gap, I would do it like this:

```css
.settings form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.settings p {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.column-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.column-wrap:nth-child(odd) {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.column-wrap:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.column-controls {
  width: 60%;
}

.column-controls input {
  width: 100%;
  /* change this so input reaches edge of cell */
  text-align: center;
}

.row-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.heading {
  border-bottom: solid 2px green;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <form>
    <p class="heading">Properties (ellipse)</p>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Position</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cx" name="cx" value="60">
          <label for="cx"> x </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="cy" name="cy" value="40">
          <label for="cy"> y </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-wrap">
      <p>Size</p>
      <div class="column-controls row-wrap">
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="rx" name="rx" value="50">
          <label for="rx"> rx </label>
        </div>
        <div class="column-wrap">
          <input id="ry" name="ry" value="50">
          <label for="ry"> ry </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="background">
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <p> Background </p>
        <input id="fill" type="color" name="fill" value="#BDBBB8">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="border">
      <p>Border</p>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke"> Color </label>
        <input id="stroke" type="color" name="stroke" value="#0000ff">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-width"> Width </label>
        <input id="stroke-width" name="stroke-width" value="2">
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <label for="stroke-dasharray"> Style </label>
        <select name="stroke-dasharray">
                    <option value="8, 10" selected="">
                        dashed
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="1, 4">
                        dotted
                    </option>
                
                    
                    <option value="0">
                        solid
                    </option>
                
            </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="save">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using `padding` to give space between `.column-wrap`? is it not valid? I'm just curious

Comment: You can do but then you would have to remove the right padding from the last cell or you could do something like using nth-child odd and even to give right and left padding

Comment: okay, I understood, using width is much better options than adding extra css to remove padding.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey padding is equally good - you can make a fixed width gap with padding.  In the edited answer above, the fixed width will be only on lower widths, if you want it to always be that size and the inputs to take up the remaining space, just add `flex-basis: 50%` to the column-row

Comment: @Pete thanks a loooot, you saved my life and I learned something new, thanks!